# Swift 4 error: [<UIViewController 0x7ff66ec0ef30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key emailField

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, iboutlet

I've tried to link a couple objects in a xib file to my code for the View Controller through IBOutlets, but when I run the code I get the error

> 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< UIViewController 0x7f94dfc0f110>
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key emailField.'

I've tried deleting all the outlets and reassigning them, and checking that all the connected objects only have one respective outlet each. Also, when unlinking one element, its error goes away, but the same format of the error for a different linked element appears.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    @IBAction func toSignUp(_ sender: Any) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passField.text!, completion: nil)
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(usernameField.text!).setData([
            "name" : nameField.text!,
            "username" : usernameField.text!,
            "email" : emailField.text!
            ])

        TransitionModel().transitionModel(viewControllerName: "LoginViewController", newView: LoginViewController().view!, viewControllerCurrent: self)
    }

    @IBAction func toLogin(_ sender: Any) {

        TransitionModel().transitionModel(viewControllerName: "LoginViewController", newView: LoginViewController().view!, viewControllerCurrent: self)

    }

}

import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    @IBAction func toLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}


import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            FirebaseApp.configure()

            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "SignUpViewController", bundle: nil)
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Pono_Beta")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for responses.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you just copy paste view controller.

Goto Storyboard, Select View Controller  Open connection inspector and remove connections for  **emailField** and create new Outlet

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried that though. It still gives me an error for the new outlet. If you'd like to download my project I could push it to Git.

Comment: @EthanWilk You have created Fresh storyboard & ViewController or you have copied from one of your project  Please add code to git I will take a look when I get some time :) ?

Comment: @EthanWilk- push your code to Git repo, will check & update.

Comment: @EthanWilk check Git repo, its only with copy references.

Comment: @EthanWilk If you are using XIB then make sure you have assign class as File's Owner

Comment: @Rocky Oh sorry I've updated it :) github.com/ewilk0/xcode

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Sorry, how do I do this? :)